# MigraDoc italic text overlapping

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

With the following code below, the text within and after the double quotes is overlapping. It seems related to the font selection, however I may not be able to change that.

Is there a way or property available to increase the width between characters? Or some workaround?

```
Document document = new Document();
Section section = document.AddSection();
Paragraph paragraph = section.AddParagraph();
Font _fontTimes14Italic = new Font("Times New Roman", "14pt") { Italic = true };
paragraph.AddFormattedText("This is a test \"The Broken\" should display incorrectly", _fontTimes14Italic);

PdfDocumentRenderer renderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(true,
PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfFontEmbedding.Always);

renderer.Document = document;
renderer.RenderDocument();
renderer.PdfDocument.Save(filePath);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug of the WPF build of PDFsharp.
Switch to the GDI+ build (can also be used for WPF applications) and the text will render correctly.
This bug will be fixed with the next release of PDFsharp (which is long overdue but I cannot say when it will come).